# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^n$. Determine if the following series converges or diverges

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm struggling with this series. Could you try to help me me?

> Determine if the following series converges or diverges.$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{z}{1-z}\right)^n$$
>   I know that it converges absolutely if Re z<$\frac{1}{2}$. But I can't move on.

Comment: This is just $\zeta\left(\dfrac{-z}{z+1}\right)$

Comment: @KennyLau I thought it was a geometric plum.

Comment: It's more of an orange.

Comment: That's not nice to change the question *after* answers have been posted.

Comment: I am sorry. I was wrong since the beginning and I didn't pay attention.

Answer (score 2):

Hint (*edited after question was changed*):

$$
\begin{alignat*}{3}
\left|\frac{z}{1-z}\right| \lt 1 \;\;&\iff\;\; |z|^2 \lt |1-z|^2 & &= (1-z)(1 - \bar z) \\
 & & &= 1 - z - \bar z + z \bar z \\ 
 & & &= |z|^2 - 2 \operatorname{Re}(z)+1 \\ 
 &\iff\;\; \operatorname{Re}(z) \lt \,\frac{1}{2}
\end{alignat*}
$$